# Is there a way to make a 12 VDC, 5 A touch toggle button without a relay to control the load (5 A max)?

Tags: mosfet, toggle-switch

I need to find out if it is possible to make such toggle button to be used to turn on/off a load not bigger than 5 A at 12 VDC (car battery). Can a [Z44N](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRFZ44N-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf) MOSFET handle this? Something similar to the picture, but able to handle more current.

[image]

Comment: MOSFETs are available up to hundreds of ampere. Do you already have the touch toggle?

Comment: no, it is an experiment i want to try but use it for real if works: i want to see if it can handle turning on/off a 5A car mini amplifier using a PAM8610 or TDA 7297, both 15w x 2

Comment: Alright. Start with the touch button and report back when it’s working or you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a classic toggle circuit from a past StackEx thread.

[Reduce current in momentary latch toggle / source capacitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342880/reduce-current-in-momentary-latch-toggle-source-capacitors)

[image]

This, plus a sufficiently large power MOSFET, should do what you want.  You must add a power supply decoupling capacitor across the gate's power pins.

To this I would add a high-value resistor from the MOSFET gate to its source so it remains off when the circuit is not powered.  This also reduces the circuit's susceptibility to radiated noise.