# How can I make/find very small on/off 3x3x3 mm switches?

Tags: switches

I'm looking for very small on/off switch that fit in a 3x3x3 mm bounding box. The application is a tiny figure and all the electronics need to be contained within the body. There is an LED, coin battery, resistor and switch. There isn’t much space left in the body.

The smallest switch I could find is 7.2x2.5x2.5 but it is not small enough.

I considered making my own but I am struggling to come up with ideas to make such a tiny switch. It needs to be easy to make and strong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Updated details to avoid asking where you could buy them.

Comment: digikey.com enable the column that shows size.

Comment: Sorry @mkeith but what do you mean by that? I’m new in the community...

Comment: Digikey allows you to search for components by many, many attributes. (Parametric search.) If you first search for switches, then narrow down your search by size of component, you should be able to quickly find the smallest switch they have on digikey. Some attributes may be hidden by default, but you can enable them with a button. Just go to digikey.com and play with it for 20 or 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing for you to do is to consider using a simple momentary switch that meets your small size requirement and then utilize a separate relay at a location where you have more room to work with. There are numerous examples to search out how you can utilize a single pole momentary switch to turn a relay into an on/off alternate action. Some of these use extra contacts on the relay to keep the relay coil energized when the circuit is in the "latched on" condition. Others add some small signal components (resistors, capacitors, diodes and/or transistors) to add the alternate action to a momentary button and then drive the relay coil accordingly.

I'll have to leave it to you to figure out just which approach will be best for your application because you left no details about the rest of your design and how the switch would be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated the question with more details. The whole circuit needs to be contained within a figure’s body so there can’t be any external components like the relay suggestion, which I understood would be an external component?

Comment: @joanfihu the rough idea is to take a momentary push button and convert it to an on/off toggling switch logically. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/make-a-momentary-switch-control-a-toggle) question; the answer with the two inverters (the accepted one) is fine, because you can get dual-inverter [ICs](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74aup2g240) ([another one](https://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NC7WZ14)) in packages that take up as little as 1.4mm², and you'd only need two resistors and a capacitor – that'd make a good thing to put below the button.