# Converting momentary button presses to states

Tags: digital-logic, input, state-machines

The goal is to implement a circuit in hardware with 2 inputs (A, B) and 2 outputs (A On, B On). An input (button press) toggles it's respective output, but also turns off the other output.

State diagram:

[image]

I've tried modifying a T-flop solution from the related question, but I can't get it to work.

Related to:
[Make a momentary switch control a toggle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/make-a-momentary-switch-control-a-toggle)

EDIT:

- By a button press I mean a transition (positive or negative)
- To clarify the states:

  - 'A On' means A is on, B is off
  - 'B On' means B is on, A is off
  - 'Off' means A is off, B is off
- Off is the initial or reset state

Comment: I am finding your question to be confusing.  Do you want two separate buttons?  If so, your state diagram is both not complete as well as misleading.  You need to show BOTH outputs and all state transitions.

Comment: Should that infinitely switch between A on and off if i press and hold a?

Comment: what if both A and B are pressed simultaneously by the user? and what is the state on reset?

Comment: I've amended the OP, hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Does the system start with both A and B Off?  Do you need to get to the "Both Off" state after having A or B  on?

Comment: @andrey To include debouncing, you'll want at least 7 states, not three. This will also take care of combinations that may lead to conceptual difficulties, as well. (Such that if B is pressed but not yet released and then A is pressed before then, what is supposed to occur? Stuff like that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDOBON.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Give that a try and see what happens.  It's assumed the inputs are low true, pulled up and debounced external to the schematic.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work. In my test, I set INA to 1 and put a 1Hz clock on INB. It doesn't work as I would expect -- OUTB being the inverse of INB.

Comment: Is this in simulation or on the bench?  Can you post a schematic?  One thing to note is that these registers operate on the positive clock edge--the low period of the input sets the latch, and the rising edge activates the flip flop once the latch has settled.

Comment: In the CircuitLab simulation. Same schematic. INA is held high, INB is pulsed -- https://imgur.com/a/b8aOKOj. Also simulated using LTSpice, got a different, but wrong, result -- https://imgur.com/a/3qe2orZ

Comment: The CircuitLab simulation looks like exactly what I'd expect...each time INB goes high, OUTB toggles.  Since INB is in the foreground, when you can't see OUTB it's because it's in the same state as INB.  That's how I understood your description of the behavior...if you push B while it's in state B_on, it goes back to off.  Not sure about the LTSpice one, it doesn't even look like the latch is acting properly in that simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scheme using two latching push button switches with 1NO + 1NC contacts.

[image]

The bulb loads shown are illustrative.