# What is the name of the electrical latch with one toggle input?

Tags: latch

For example pressing a momentary push button to toggle an led off and on through a Flip-Flop.

I’ve only seen the ones where there are two buttons and you press both to switch the states.

However I know one exists where you only have to push one momentary button to alternate between the states of the Flip-Flip.

*Edited thread to be more contextual as suggested by @Jack Soldano, Thank you all!*

Comment: I think you are looking for a T flip-flop: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/t-is-for-toggle-understanding-the-t-flip-flop/

Comment: [Toggle flip flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#T_flip-flop)

Comment: You may find more information at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/make-a-momentary-switch-control-a-toggle

Answer (score 1):

I think you are describing either a Latching Switch Push button compared to two momentary switches?

[image]

Or you could be describing a Toggle Flip Flop circuit connected to a momentary switch?

[image]

They look something like this, they don't need the clock signal and can just work with the feedback and Toggle inputs.

If you have a microcontroller you can write this functionality in software and make any trigger input work like this.

This is not a very well worded question, what is the context of this question?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. What would you find ideal wording of a question?

Comment: A bit more detail on what you meant by 'Latch' and in what context would always help. My initial reading of the question made me think you were referring to the electronics Toggle Flip Flop but then after reading your description I felt like you were asking about different types of mechanical switch. I'm still not sure what one you are asking about? :) did I answer your question?

Comment: You did answer my question. :)  I will be keeping what you said about question wording in mind for this one and any other question in the future.