# Activate CE pin of a LDO voltage regulator with a momentary switch

Tags: switches, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, ldo

The situation is as follows:
I have a 3.3V regulator that I would like to turn on and off by a momentary switch connected to its "CE" pin.
This regulator has an input from a 3.7V battery and an output to a microcontroller (3.3V).

My question is, what is the simplest possible circuit that can be used so that pressing the switch once will turn the regulator off and then on again?

I cannot use software with the microcontroller as my intention is to turn the system off completely and I would not be able to turn it back on.

Comment: Use the switch to turn it on; have the MCU hold it on as long as it wants to be, then turn itself off.

Comment: I said I can't use the MCU.
And the switch is momentary, that means that it only lets the current through when it is held down. If you let go, it opens the circuit.

Comment: It's not nonsense at all but something widely done.  The button gets things started, the MCU starts up all but instantly and holds the enable active.

Comment: What is the part number of the regulator?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4060/make-a-momentary-switch-control-a-toggle this question might help

Comment: @ChrisStratton I may have misunderstood your proposal, how do you turn the system on and off with the same momentary switch? The idea is to turn the system off and on manually, no software. The solution should not depend on the MCU at all. Thank you.

Comment: You use the button to kickstart things and to tell the software to it's time to turn things off.

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/555261/how-to-toggle-relay-with-single-push-button/666248#666248):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa4k4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It employs a D-type flip flop to toggle output CE between high and low with each momentary press of SW1. Here I use a [4013](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4013b.pdf), but you could replace it with a [74HC74](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/74HC74-108792.pdf) (the pinout will be different). The 4013 can be powered from between 3V and 15V, the 74HC74 between 2V and 6V.

C1 and R1 cause CE to be low after power is applied. Use the SET input instead of RESET if you wish CE to initialise high at power-on.

C2, R2 and R3 are to debounce button presses. Each press should cause the state of CE to invert.

There are two flip-flops in these packages. If you don't intend to use the other unit, be sure to connect all its inputs (as shown) to a fixed potential, to avoid oscillations and excessive power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JK Flip-Flop to achieve this. By setting the J and K inputs HIGH, you will be able to use the Flip-Flop as a toggle device to set the CE pin on your LDO HIGH or LOW, depending on the toggle state. A couple of notes:

- Remember that a JK Flip-Flop will maintain it's previous state when the power is turned off. Having a circuit to reset the Flip-Flop would be helpful if this is not desirable.
- Be careful with debounce. Add capacitors to the input if needed to combat this.

Comment: And how will you power the flip flop?  Really you aren't achieving anything you couldn't with the MCU itself, and you add the bouncing sensitivity.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The OP couldn't use a microcontroller, stated in his post, so this was a suggested alternative. And the Flip Flop can be powered by the 3.7V battery.

Comment: @Jay I liked your proposal, I will think about it to make a good design.

Comment: The op's belief that they can't use the MCU is simply mistaken.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I won't continue to commit on the best way for the OP to achieve the desired results, but they clearly stated that they wanted a hardware based solution, not a software based one. I do agree that you have more flexibility with a microcontroller, but that's not what the OP wants.

Comment: @ChrisStratton My device depends on a very small battery because it is small, as a designer I have to evaluate the best option.I can apply both alternatives, on one hand sacrifice physical space by adding a toggle flip-flop or on the other hand, leave the MCU always on in sleep/active mode and wake it up and turn it off with a button. But I would have to control the other IC's in the system with the MCU.
In this case, the requirement to decide for one solution or another, is the consumption in sleep mode.
I appreciate both alternatives, I am really studying the best way to do it.

Comment: What you are still not understanding is that the MCU can control the regulator powering it.